# Do I need to worry about an object being thread safe if it has no static fields?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, thread-safety, singleton

I'm writing a decorator to implement caching.  The object will be registered as a singleton by my DI container.  Because I know I'm registering my object as a singleton, the field representing my cache is not static.  I'm not sure if this is best practice, but I'm trying to avoid locking at all cost.  My cache is lazily initialized and an expensive/run only once operation.  My question is do I need to worry about multiple threads running the cache initialization logic?  My gut tells me "yes I do need to worry", but I've heard other devs say "No point in locking if it's not static".

```
//SimpleInjector DI Container configuration
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void ConfigureContainer(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<IQueryHandler<GetFoos, Foo[]>, GetFoosHandler>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.RegisterDecorator<IQueryHandler<GetFoos, Foo[]>, GetFoosCachingHandler>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id;
    public string FooTypeCode;
    public string Name;
}

public class GetFoos : IQuery<Foo[]>
{
    public string FooTypeCode;
}

public class GetFoosCachingHandler : IQueryHandler<GetFoos, Foo[]>
{
    private Lazy<Dictionary<string, Foo[]>> _cache;

    private readonly IQueryHandler<GetFoos, Foo[]> _queryHandler;

    public GetFoosCachingHandler(IQueryHandler<GetFoos, Foo[]> queryHandler)
    {
        _queryHandler = queryHandler;

        _cache = new Lazy<Dictionary<string, Foo[]>>(() =>
        {
            //expensive and run only once operation e.g. subscribe to bus for cache invalid messages and reset cache

            return new Dictionary<string, Foo[]>();
        });
    }

    public Foo[] Handle(GetFoos query)
    {
        var cache = _cache.Value;

        if (!cache.ContainsKey(query.FooTypeCode))
        {
            cache[query.FooTypeCode] = _queryHandler.Handle(new GetFoos { FooTypeCode = query.FooTypeCode });
        }

        return cache[query.FooTypeCode];
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless I am completely misreading your code, it is not a singleton.  You'll be setting _cache every time you create GetFoosCachingHandler, so there isn't a need to lock..

Comment: Now, if you DID have a singleton, you would want to be very careful about setting _cache and surround that with lock() to ensure thread safety.  But it would really only be necessary to do that lock() once, so there is no real performance issue.

Comment: Oh, by the way, I think _cache would be static in a singleton.  I'm assuming that you want all callers to get the same cache.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jeff.  When I configure my DI container at start up, I register it as a Singleton.  Added what this looks like above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need locking to prevent multiple threads from running the same code.

> "No point in locking if it's not static"

That only applies when each thread has its own instance of a class. As soon as you share an instance between threads, you need to synchonise the access.

Comment: Good point. Also other way is true too - if static data is not shared across the threads there is no need for locking... The fact that static fields are usually accessied by multiple threads does not in any way imply that locking or not somehow related to fields being static. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation

Answer (score 1):

Guffa is right. Nothing to add at this point. What I would like to add is a little refactoring. You should probably extract the caching behavior from the decorator as follows:

```
public class GetFoosCachingHandler : IQueryHandler<GetFoos, Foo[]>{
    private readonly ICache _cache;
    private readonly IQueryHandler<GetFoos, Foo[]> _queryHandler;

    public GetFoosCachingHandler(ICache cache, IQueryHandler<GetFoos, Foo[]> queryHandler){
        _cache = cache;
        _queryHandler = queryHandler;
    }

    public Foo[] Handle(GetFoos query) {
        var result = _cache.Load<Foo[]>(query.FooTypeCode);

        if (result == null) {
            _cache.Store<Foo[]>(query.FooTypeCode, result = _queryHandler.Handle(query));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

A few things to note here:

- A decorator should not create a query, but simply pass on the incoming query message to its decoratee.
- You might want to create a generic caching decorator instead; this allows you to apply it to multiple handlers.
- The use of the Lazy is useless, because creating a `Dictionary<,>` is really lightweight and the dictionary is always created.
- If you make the decorator generic, you need a different way of determining the cache keys. What has worked out great for me in the past is to serialize the complete query message to JSON (using JSON.NET) and use that as key. You might want to do the same with the result, because those results are mutable objects (both `Foo` is and array is), making it dangerous to reuse them on multiple threads (you never know who changes them).

Comment: Thanks for the direction @Steven!  Yes, I need to make my cache results immutable.  What if I made my queries immutable and IEquatable too?  Could you think of any reason I wouldn't want to do that?  I guess I'd have to make sure all properties of a query were immutable as well.

Comment: Making objects immutable is a lot of work in C#. IMO its not worth the trouble. It's much easier to give each request it's own freshly deserialized objects. Or define all your query and response types in F# and consume them in C#. Best of both worlds.